# Member function undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-class

I have made this class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

import Auth from '../api/Auth';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            alreadyLoggedIn: true
        };
        this.redirectToHome.bind(this);
        this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        Auth.isAlreadyLoggedIn().then((res) => {
            if(res == true) {
                this.redirectToHome();
            } else {
                this.setState({alreadyLoggedIn: false});
            }
        });
    }

    redirectToHome() {
        this.props.navigator.resetTo({
            screen: 'homeScreen',
            title: 'Meetups'
        });
    }

    loginWithFacebook() {
        Auth.loginWithFacebook().then((success) => {
            if(success == true) {
                this.redirectToHome();
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                {this.state.alreadyLoggedIn == false &&
                    <Button title="Login with Facebook" onPress={this.loginWithFacebook} />
                }
                {this.state.alreadyLoggedIn == true &&
                    <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.alreadyLoggedIn} />
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
 }
```

Inside the `loginWithFacebook` function, when it reaches the line where it calls the `redirectToHome` function, it says this:

```
_this3.redirectToHome is not a function
```

[image]

Am I accessing this function in a wrong manner? I can't make the function static and it required the `this` object.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have done the binding for the functions incorrectly in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        alreadyLoggedIn: true
    };
    this.redirectToHome = this.redirectToHome.bind(this);
    this.loginWithFacebook = this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this);
}
```

`this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this);` will return a new function after proper binding and you then need to use the function returned. Now since you did not assign this newly added function, with `this.loginWithFacebook` you will be refererring to your own defined function without the binding and hence `this.redirectToHome` won't work since `this` inside it wont refer to the correct context

Comment: It worked! But why does it work when I just use `this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this)` ? I mean after this, I am able to do `this.props` inside loginWithFacebook function without updating it in the constructor

Comment: because you're only using one of the two as an event handler. I would just not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually update the 'member functions' in the constructor:

```
this.redirectToHome = this.redirectToHome.bind(this);
this.loginWithFacebook = this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this);
```

Comment: It worked! But why does it work when I just use `this.loginWithFacebook.bind(this)` ? I mean after this, I am able to do this.props inside loginWithFacebook function without updating it in the constructor